# JSF Resource sends 304 not modified afer redeployment

Tags: jsf, resources, glassfish

I use outputStylesheet and outputScript for some resources. 
But when I've made changes to the development project and want to redeploy in the production environment (upload the WAR to Glassfish admin console) the response code for the resources are 304 (not modified) which means that the browser wont pickup the changes before the caches are reset.

Any ideas? I use JSF2 and Glassfish v3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. Then I tried it on Glassfish 3.1-b25, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried upgrading the version of GlassFish, but if that doesn't work you could try setting the max-age or expires headers to some small value.

Alternatively, you can use touch (only on UNIX) to update the modified date on the static content after a redeploy.

Comment: Also hit CTRL-F5 on your browser to force a refresh without going through the cache.